# Nginx Server Block for IP address

Tags: webserver, nginx, routing

I know editing `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` isn't the proper way to configure nginx on ubuntu.

Usually one uses something like `/etc/nginx/sites-available`

What would the folder structure be if I'm in a stage of development where I don't yet have a domain name? (e.g. just using an IP address)

Answer (score 0):

I'm realizing that the name is actually arbitrary.

One can name it anything and it should work as specifics are specified in the config file itself.

Also there is by default a file called `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`, which is a great to use when you only have an IP address setup.